# Why i will need to convert numbers in this assembly game

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to make a guessing game using assembly language.

> The game asks the player to enter a number and compares it against
>   another number set, it then tells the player whether their guess is
>   too high or too low and allows the player to keep guessing until they
>   get the number set.

One of the questions of that work is:

> Why number conversion is needed and how – using the grid method-
>   conversion between ASCII H occurs from Hex to binary

Why will I need to do the conversion ?

game code

```
.data #storing data
    startmsg: .asciiz "I am thinking of a random number between 1 and 100\n\n"
    guessmsg: .asciiz "Enter your guess\n"
    tooHigh: .asciiz "Your guess is too high.\n"
    tooLow: .asciiz "\n\nYour guess is too low.\n"
    wingame: .asciiz "You have guessed the number. Well done!\n\n"
.text #start of program

start:
    jal random
    add $t0, $zero, $a0 # store random number $a0 in $t0
    li $v0, 4         # print string
    la $a0, startmsg
    syscall

#######################################
# Main game loop for guessing
guessing:
    la $a0, guessmsg
    li $v0, 4 # print string guessmsg
    syscall




    li $v0, 5 #read int from user
    syscall
        move $t1, $v0 # store input in t1
        #addi $t2, $zero, 1 #t2 = 1 (guess min)
    beq $t0, $t1, win # if stored int = user input, user won
    addi $s0, $s0, -1 # guess used, subtract
    blt $t0, $t1, goLower # if stored int < user input, guess is too high

    # otherwise, guess is too low
    la $a0, tooLow
    li $v0, 4 # print string tooLow
        syscall

    # loop guessing
    j guessing

#######################################
# goLower: Procedure if the user guess too high
goLower:
    la $a0, tooHigh
    li $v0, 4 # print tooHigh
    syscall
    # loop back to get another guess
    j guessing

#######################################
# User won, print win and restart
win:
    la $a0, wingame
    li $v0, 4 #print string wingame
    syscall
    j start


#############################################
# LEAF PROCEDURE
# random: generate a rand number between 0 - 100
random: 
    li $v0, 42        # SERVICE 41 for a rand int
    #addi $a0, $zero, 0 # random number >= 0
    addi $a1, $zero, 100 #random number < 100
    #xor $a0, $a0, $a0  # Select random generator 0
    syscall            # Generate random int (returns in $a0)
    jr $ra
```

Comment: You don't need to if you implement the comparison in the text format.

Comment: @Jester in text format you mean string I/O ?

Comment: Yes, remember all input (everything you read) will be ASCII characters (even if those characters are digits). If you can compare the character input to make whatever determination you need, you can avoid the conversion from character to integer values. If the input is a single ASCII digit, then a direct comparison without more is trivial. Otherwise you will have to traverse the input until one of the digits is greater/less than the corresponding character from the set. If your set is integer values -- then doing the conversion makes sense. Otherwise, take a character approach.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you so much for the explanation, can i put the code of the game and tell me how to modify it to work with ASCII digit and convert method ?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i modified the question with the code, please check and tell me how it work and if there's a conversion, thank you

Comment: you dont, if the user enters "10" that is 0x31 and 0x30 you could turn that into a single value 0x3130.  if they are searching for the value "11" and you have prepped that to be 0x3131, then you can compare the 0x3130 to 0x3131 and the comparison will work dont need to do it character by character.  now you might want to validate that each character input is a valid number, base 10 would be 0x30 to 0x39.

Answer (score 0):

The code as it is now is using the service read_int (system call code 5) by calling it with

```
li $v0, 5 #read int from user
syscall
```

Now if what you want is to read ASCII characters you should use the service read_string (system call code 8) which will store the read buffer in `$a0` and the length of it in `$a1`.

```
li $v0, 8 # Note the only change is 8 instead of 5
syscall
```

Now to compare the input number with the number in the code you have two options:

- Write your code so that the code generated number set is in ASCII format and compare the two ASCII values.
- Convert the user imput ASCII character to decimal and compare the numbers.

For the first one you need to split the number in it's digits, add 48 to them and concatenate the results in a string.

For the second solution you need to iterate through the buffer and substract 48 to every ASCII character.

This is the algorithm to convert an ASCII array to integer but to work it assumes that you stored the buffer in `$s1`, `$t0` contains `10`, and `$s2` contains `0`:

```
lp:
  lbu $t1, ($s1)       #load unsigned char from array into t1
  beq $t1, $0, FIN     #NULL terminator found
  blt $t1, 48, error   #check if char is not a digit (ascii<'0')
  bgt $t1, 57, error   #check if char is not a digit (ascii>'9')
  addi $t1, $t1, -48   #converts t1's ascii value to dec value
  mul $s2, $s2, $t0    #sum *= 10
  add $s2, $s2, $t1    #sum += array[s1]-'0'
  addi $s1, $s1, 1     #increment array address
  j lp                 #jump to start of loop
```

Comment: Huh?  Where does `int 21h` come from?  It is not in the original question, which is not x86 assembly.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, i updated the question with the code, can you tell me if it work with convert or not, and which instruction responsible for that

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm maybe because he didn't saw the code, i updated the question minutes ago :)

Comment: i think it's li $v0, 5 if yes, how can i change it to convert method ? (sorry i'm beginner)

Comment: Sorry I replied before you uploaded your code and I assumed that as a beginner you were using some older (simpler) assembly. Now by looking at your code yes, `li $v0, 5` Is the command that says to `syscall` to read from keyboard input, but if I recall correctly this automatically reads an int and not an ASCII, and in the code I don't seem to see any data conversion so I'm not sure about what's the question

Comment: @ssoBAekiL yes the code working properly, but my question is, how can i change it to read ASCII and convert it to int

Comment: @ssoBAekiL someone said, `ASCII digits can simply be converted to integer binary numbers by subtracting the character '0' from them.

`  how can i do that ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand the problem properly the first time, I have edited my answer, hope it's helpful to you

Comment: @ssoBAekiL can you please also add how to convert `li $v0, 8 syscall` to int

Comment: @ssoBAekiL if i stored the buffer in $s1, $t0 contains 10, and $s2 contains 0, is the random number 1 to 100 will still working ? if yes, how can i do that

Comment: No since the random number is stored in `$t0` but you can change it to make it work. The best way to learn is by trying what works and what doesnt, I gave you most of the information needed, you should try to find the final solution

Comment: @ssoBAekiL thank you, appreciate your effort,  last question, is that grid conversion method ? and where i put it, ?( before or after what ?)

Comment: @user12734691: The 2nd code block of this answer has a comment that says the *only* change is the call number from 5 to 8.  And the way the text around it is phrased, it sounds like `$a0` and `$a1` are *return* values from the system call.  They aren't, they're other inputs that are required.  https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html. 
 You need to reserve space somewhere for the string, and pass a pointer and max-length in $a0 and $a1, unlike the read_int call.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok, as i said i'm a beginner, can you post an answer with the modified code, changing my code from reading directly int value to reding ASCII then converting it to int ? i'll appreciate it

Comment: @user12734691: There are plenty of examples of using the read string system call on Stack Overflow; search for them with google for something like `site:stackoverflow.com MIPS read string syscall`.  Then you can use the rest of this answer to implement a `total = total*10 + digit - '0'` loop.  Or wait for @  ssoBAekiL to fix this answer.